# Grid layout images need to be set up dunamically without height and width

Tags: html, css

I am working on the grid layout images. Somewhat I had achieved layout by using height and width. but I want to get the images to be set up dynamically without height and width.

**I am expecting the output without height and width. below is the grid layout image:**

[image]

What I had achieved by using height and width that is not the right i want to set up dynamically the images height and width below is the codepen link.
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/arshiyakhanam_786/pen/GRJOKpo)

In place of the blue background, I want the image.

How can i achieve that layout? Can anyone suggest me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance...

```css
.section-inner {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.ansa-gallery-items {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px 0 60px;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.ansa-gallery-items2 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    margin-left: 150px;
  
    align-items: center;
}
.grid-img {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
#grid-img-left {
    margin-bottom: -45px;
}
.ansa-item-img.img-1 {
    height: 250px;
    width: 525px;
}
.ansa-item-img.img-2,
.ansa-item-img.img-4 {
/*     margin-left: 25px; */
    height: 380px;
    width: 315px;
    
}
#grid-img-right {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.ansa-item-img.img-3,
.ansa-item-img.img-5 {
/*     margin-left: 30px;
    width: 330px;
    height: 200px; */
  
      height: 300px;
    width: 280px;
}
/* .ansa-item-img.img-4 {
    width: 780px;
    height: 290px;
} */
/* .ansa-item-img.img-5 {
    margin-top: -192px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 330px;
    height: 480px;
} */
.ansa-mansory-item {
/*     margin-top: 30px; */
  
}
.ansa-item-img {
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
/* #ansa-load {
    display: none;
} */
.ansa-mansory-item figure {
    margin: 0;
}
#grid-img-left2 {
/*     margin-left: 100px; */
}
#grid-img-center {
    margin: 0 30px;
}
div#grid-img-right2 {
/*     margin-left: 30px; */
    margin-top: -175px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ansa-slider-media">
  <div class="section-inner">
<!--    <h2 class="ansa-media-tilte">Gallery</h2> -->
   <div class="masonry-grid">
    <div class="ansa-gallery-items">
        <div class="ansa-mansory-item">
              <div class="grid-img" id="grid-img-left">
                
         <figure><img class="ansa-item-img img-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/9G432QJ/blend.jpg" class="ansa-thumb"></figure>
        </div>
              </div>
        <div class="ansa-mansory-item">
              <div class="grid-img" id="grid-img-right">
         <figure><img class="ansa-item-img img-2" src="https://i.ibb.co/9G432QJ/blend.jpg" class="ansa-thumb"></figure>
        </div>
              </div>
    </div>
        
        <div class="ansa-gallery-items2">
        <div class="ansa-mansory-item">
              <div class="grid-img" id="grid-img-left2">
                
         <figure><img class="ansa-item-img img-3" src="https://i.ibb.co/9G432QJ/blend.jpg" class="ansa-thumb"></figure>
        </div>
              </div>
        <div class="ansa-mansory-item">
              <div class="grid-img" id="grid-img-center">
         <figure><img class="ansa-item-img img-4" src="https://i.ibb.co/9G432QJ/blend.jpg" class="ansa-thumb"></figure>
        </div>
              </div>
           <div class="ansa-mansory-item">
              <div class="grid-img" id="grid-img-right2">
         <figure><img class="ansa-item-img img-5" src="https://i.ibb.co/9G432QJ/blend.jpg" class="ansa-thumb"></figure>
        </div>
              </div>
    </div>
<!--     <div class="ansa-gallery-items">
        <div class="ansa-mansory-item">
         <figure><img class="ansa-item-img img-4" src="https://i.ibb.co/9G432QJ/blend.jpg" class="ansa-thumb"></figure>
        </div>
        <div class="ansa-mansory-item">
         <figure><img class="ansa-item-img img-5" src="https://i.ibb.co/9G432QJ/blend.jpg" class="ansa-thumb"></figure>
        </div>
             <div class="ansa-mansory-item">
         <figure><img class="ansa-item-img img-3" src="https://i.ibb.co/9G432QJ/blend.jpg" class="ansa-thumb"></figure>
        </div>
    </div> -->
   </div> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Nothing in the question could be described as a grid

Comment: I want the above grid layout images to be set dynamically without using height and width its like similar to masonry layout.

Comment: But there is no grid. A grid has rows and columns and your image does not.

Comment: I don't want the rows and columns I want to use the flex properties.

Comment: Flex uses rows so it's of no use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do that without width and height.

If you are gonna have multiple images with different sizes, the container can only rely on image size or specific width and height.

You could crop all images to the desired size or you could use JavaScript to define the image actual size and then make it smaller or bigger and also set container to portrait or landscape.

Here is a simple jQuery solution that checks the image size and then if the width is larger then the height, it puts specific class on that image.

```
$( window ).on( "load", function() {  
  $("img.ansa-item-img").each(function() {  
    var width = this.width,
        height = this.height;

    if(width > height) {
       $(this).addClass('landscape')
    } else (
      $(this).addClass('portrait')
    )
  });  
});
```

Just add the class style to the CSS file like this:

```
.portrait {
  width: 150px;
  height: 350px;
}

.landscape {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

This way, you can upload different sizes and it will automatically fit the image in the container and set the orientation.

Comment: If you know how to set up the images height and width by using javascript please help me to solve it.

Comment: When i am using the jQuery only landscape properties are calling portrait properties are not calling.

Comment: That is because you have only landscape-oriented images. Try to use different images to test. You can use placeholder images for a test (https://placeholder.com/).